# Private type definitions in VSCode Lua

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

I am using VSCode with the "Lua" extension by sumneko.  I would like to define some types in one of my files, but I don't want to share the types with every other file in my project.

Unfortunately, if I do the simple thing and write:

```
--[[ a.lua ]]
---@class foo: {x: integer, y: string}

--[[ b.lua ]]
---@type foo
local x
x.|  -- <- place cursor here
```

Then I receive suggestions for the the `x` and `y` fields of the `foo` type, even though I haven't imported `a.lua`.  Instead, I would like `b.lua` to tell me that the `foo` type is unknown, so I can either import it from `a.lua` or create a separate definition.

How can I keep a type definition "private" to a file in VSCode?